# HOW do you get this answer?

Tags: economics, percentages

I am stuck on this problem even as simple as it may seem. The problem is:

If the price level increases 20%, the purchasing power of money decreases by what percentage?

answer: 16.67%

The equation the book gives me is V = 1/P, 
where V is the purchasing power and P is the price level.

I have tried V = 1/1.2 but I only get 0.83

Comment: ...and 0.83 is how much lower than 1.0?

Comment: $100-100\times 0.83 \approx 16.67\%$

Comment: its 0.17, but i need to know how to get that exact answer

Comment: AAHHHH!! 1-(1/1.2) = 0.166

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have $\$1.00$.  The thing that you had planned to buy that yesterday cost $\$1.00$ now costs $\$1.20$.  So you can only buy $\frac56$ of the thing.  Thus you have lost $\frac16$ of your purchasing power, or $16 \frac23 \%$